# Json.NET: Serialization Callbacks in base object

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

Using Json.NET are Serialization Callbacks supported when the OnDeserializedAttribute is placed on a base class method?  For example using this object graph:

```
[DataContract]
public class StubData:StubBase {}

[DataContract]
public class StubBase {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context) {
        Id = "1";
    }
}

var stubData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StubData>(@"{""anyData"":""Foo""}");

stubData.Id //returns 1
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it should be easy to self-answer just by running it, no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `OnDeserialized` is supported. See [the documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationCallbacks.htm)

Here's a working [cs-script](http://www.csscript.net/) example. Needs Newtonsoft.Json.dll is the same directory

```
//css_ref Newtonsoft.Json.dll

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public class StubData:StubBase {}

public class StubBase {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context) {
        Id = "1";
    }
}

class Script
{
    [STAThread]
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var stubData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StubData>(@"{""anyData"":""Foo""}");
      Console.WriteLine(stubData.Id); //returns 1
    }
}
```

This prints

```
1
```

Comment: But the attribute is designated as Inherited = false. Doesn't that mean the attribute does not apply to derived objects?

Comment: I think he is asking for JSON.Net, not Newtonsoft...

Answer (score 0):

After checking [Table of differences between Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#table-of-differences-between-newtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson) out, Callbacks are stated as [Not supported, workaround, sample:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#callbacks)

> `Newtonsoft.Json` lets you execute custom code at several points in the
> serialization or deserialization process:
>
> - OnDeserializing (when beginning to deserialize an object)
> - OnDeserialized (when finished deserializing an object)
> - OnSerializing (when beginning to serialize an object)
> - OnSerialized (when finished serializing an object)
>
> In [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json), you can simulate callbacks by writing a custom
> converter. The following example shows a custom converter for a POCO.
> The converter includes code that displays a message at each point that
> corresponds to a `Newtonsoft.Json` callback.

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace SystemTextJsonSamples
{
    public class WeatherForecastCallbacksConverter : JsonConverter<WeatherForecast>
    {
        public override WeatherForecast Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type type,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // Place "before" code here (OnDeserializing),
            // but note that there is no access here to the POCO instance.
            Console.WriteLine("OnDeserializing");

            // Don't pass in options when recursively calling Deserialize.
            WeatherForecast forecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(ref reader);

            // Place "after" code here (OnDeserialized)
            Console.WriteLine("OnDeserialized");

            return forecast;
        }

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            WeatherForecast forecast, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // Place "before" code here (OnSerializing)
            Console.WriteLine("OnSerializing");

            // Don't pass in options when recursively calling Serialize.
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, forecast);

            // Place "after" code here (OnSerialized)
            Console.WriteLine("OnSerialized");
        }
    }
}
```

> Register this custom converter by [adding the converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#registration-sample---converters-collection) to the
> [Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_Converters) collection.
>
> If you use a custom converter that follows the preceding sample:
>
> - The `OnDeserializing` code doesn't have access to the new POCO instance. To manipulate the new POCO instance at the start of
>   deserialization, put that code in the POCO constructor.
> - Avoid an infinite loop by registering the converter in the options object and not passing in the options object when recursively calling
>   `Serialize` or `Deserialize`.
>
> For more information about custom converters that recursively call
> `Serialize` or `Deserialize`, see the [Required properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#required-properties) section earlier
> in this article.