# How to handle exception raised while doing json.net deserialisation on parameterised constructor

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I am using Json.net 4.5. I have serialized PatientV1 using Json and tried desterilize into PatientV2. The serialization happens nicely.

But when I have introduced a validation check in `AppUtility.CreatePatientNr` (which throws an exception if any empty or null value is passed), the deserialisation fails.

I have tried using a derived JsonConverter to create PatientV2 object where I have the control to pass the “Proper” value to the constructor, however I will not be able to set the proper PatientNr after the object has been created since it is readonly.

I do not want to use reflection. Does Json.net provides any way to set the readonly property `patientV2.PatientNr` in the JsonConverter?

Is there any way to ignore this exception or any other way to create PatientV2 object?

```
    //version 1.0. Legacy code with no Json tag
    public class PatientV1
    {
        public int PatId { get; set; }
    }

    //Version 2.0
    public class PatientV2
    {
        public PatientV2( string Id, string s1, string s2 )
        {
            PatientNr = AppUtility.CreatePatientNr( Id, s1, s2);
        }

        //PatId is renamed to a string type. It now has private set
        [JsonProperty( "PatId" )]
        public string PatientNr { get; private set; }
    }
```

**Edit1:** Does Json has any specific constructor for deserialisation just like binary serialisation?

Comment: Why don't you try/catch the `AppUtility.CreatePatientNr` call in your constructor?

Comment: In my normal useage i want the exception to be raised, so that object should not get created if the proper values are not passed to construct. Moving the parameter validation code outside the constructor will be needing more effort for all those similar classes, so trying to figureout a better easy way

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments to a non-default constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254503/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-non-default-constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json first tries the object using default constructor and if it does not find one then it then takes up the first parameterized constructor and pass null data to it. There is no specific constructor that Json uses for construction of object just like binary serialization.

However if you are have object which implements ISerializable then serialization constructor is called.

Approaches one can use are as follows

1. In the JsonConverter create object by passing appropriate value to
   the parameterized constructor
2. Remove the business logic from constructor that might raise an
   exception.
3. Make all the persist-able as simply a structure without any
   business logic (Anemic model)

I will currently will go with approach 1) then 2) later 3). Because of legacy huge code reason approaches 2) and 3) will take some time