# Json Deserialize Protected Property

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class property set, and fixed in the constructor, example below is a `Guid.NewGuid()`..

The rationale being to only allow the class to populate, on creation.. so it's set in the constructor, and marked only as `get;` - works fine, until i serialize / deserialize to Json.

It seems that because there is no `set;` the deserialization fails.. and the constructor steps in and creates a new guid

I have tried internal, private, and protected set .. but all result in a regeneration of the property, the only way i can get it to work is by marking Id as `{get;set;}`,

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo() => Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

which then means you can simply do:

```
var obj = new Foo();
obj.Id = "Any Old Rubbish";
```

Is there a way around this at all?

Short sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Id);

        var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(serialize);
        Console.WriteLine(deserialize.Id);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public Foo() => Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Id { get; }
}
```

Output:

```
7868a298-f20d-4719-85ef-ba64c8658819
34fe422c-9555-4d17-ae1a-9fbf21af1b71
```

Comment: Better show your your `Foo` class code instead of describing it in words.

Comment: it is there on the original post? edit: ah, i see what you mean, updated! minuscule change, didn't think it was necessary....

Comment: I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB4kE.png) image of how ```JsonConvert.DeserializeObject```'s algorithm works. A detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870132/how-does-json-deserialization-in-c-sharp-work). So would you mind changing your code like so? ```var obj = new Foo(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());``` & ```public Foo(String Id) => this.Id = Id;``` Like this it will work due to the constructor call won't regenerate a guid.

Comment: @m1nkeh your code doesn't show any protected properties. It shows a read-only property. That's already supported by JSON.NET using various techniques

Comment: You can use a constructor with parameters marked with the [JsonConstructor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) attribute. You can use the [JsonProperty ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to mark a private property, field or property with a private setter for deserialization as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry, a private setter? just for deserialization?

Comment: @m1nkeh which just one of the reasons such things exist. *read-only* does mean read-only. Only the constructor can set a read-only property. Anyway, pick your technique. You can have a constructor with parameters, a private setter or a get-only property with a serialized private field

Comment: pretty sure private setter also does not work, so i think we are at the last option (get-only prop w/ serialized private field), it's the how part, can you flesh out the post with an example at all?

Comment: ohhh i get it, literally make it {get; private set; } and add [JsonProperty] ??

Answer (score 6):

The following image (it is not done by me but is found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870132/how-does-json-deserialization-in-c-sharp-work) question) shows how the algorithm for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`works. As you can see the constructor of the serialized type is called almost always. That's why you have to use a constructor with parameters as the left most path of the image shows.

[image: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject algorithm]

The following shows a modification of your example using a constructor with parameters.

```cs
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var obj = new Foo(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Id);

    var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(serialize);
    Console.WriteLine(deserialize.Id);

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}

class Foo
{
  public Foo(String Id) => this.Id = Id;        
  public string Id { get; }
}
```

This will result in having the same guid before and after serialization while there is no need to use `public string Id { get;  set;}` as you didn't want to.

Comment: This is documented and you don't even need to remove the default constructor. You can use the JsonConstructor attribute to specify *which* constructor to use. You can use `JsonProperty` to specify that even a private property, field or property with a private setter should be deserialized