# How to deserialise a missing property to an empty list in an F# record instead of null using Json.Net

Tags: f#, json.net

Consider an F# record that contains a list value such as this:

```
type MyRecord = {
    Name: string
    SomeList: string list
}
```

Using `Netwonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` to deserialise JSON to this record when the JSON does not contain a property for the list value `Values` of the record will lead to the deserialised record having a `null` value for the list instead of an empty list `[]`.

That is,

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRecord>("""{ "Name": "Some name"}""" ) |> printfn "%A"
// Gives: { Name = "Some name"; SomeList = null; }
```

How can you deserialise using `Netwonsoft.Json` so that the list is initialised to an empty list?  For example:

```
{ Name = "Some name"; SomeList = []; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) such as the following:

```ml
type ParameterizedConstructorInitializingContractResolver() =
    inherit DefaultContractResolver()

    // List is a module not a static class so it's a little inconvenient to access via reflection.  Use this wrapper instead.
    static member EmptyList<'T>() = List.empty<'T>

    override __.CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter(matchingMemberProperty : JsonProperty, parameterInfo : ParameterInfo) =
        let property = base.CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter(matchingMemberProperty, parameterInfo)
        if (not (matchingMemberProperty = null) && property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<_ list>) then
            let genericMethod = typeof<ParameterizedConstructorInitializingContractResolver>.GetMethod("EmptyList", BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Static)
            let concreteMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments())
            let defaultValue = concreteMethod.Invoke(null, null)
            property.DefaultValue <- defaultValue
            property.DefaultValueHandling <- new System.Nullable<DefaultValueHandling>(DefaultValueHandling.Populate)
            matchingMemberProperty.DefaultValue <- defaultValue
            matchingMemberProperty.DefaultValueHandling <- new System.Nullable<DefaultValueHandling>(DefaultValueHandling.Populate)
        property
```

And then use it as follows:

```ml
let settings = JsonSerializerSettings(ContractResolver = new ParameterizedConstructorInitializingContractResolver())

let myrecord1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRecord>("""{ "Name": "Missing SomeList"}""", settings )
let myrecord2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRecord>("""{ "Name": "Populated SomeList", "SomeList" : ["a", "b", "c"]}""", settings )
let myrecord3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRecord>("""{ "Name": "null SomeList", "SomeList" : null}""", settings )
```

Notes:

- The contract resolver works for any object that is [deserialized via a parameterized constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41871975/3744182), which includes, but is not limited to, f# records.  If any such object has a constructor argument with type `T list` for any `T` then the value will default to `List.empty<T>` when missing or null.
- The contract resolver reuses the same instance of the default value `List.empty<T>` for all deserialized objects, which is fine here since f# lists are immutable (and `List.empty<T>` seems to be a singleton anyway).  The same approach would not work for providing a default value for mutable collections as a constructor argument.
- You may want to [cache the contract resolver for best performance](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver).
- The constructor parameter must have the same name (modulo case) as the corresponding property.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEA2kM).

Comment: Fantastic - thank you, @dbc, and thanks also for the detailed notes!