# JSON deserialize with a private setter

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I'm having a problem with JSON when I try to deserialize to a class.
My current code

```
    Public Class Client

        Public Property status As Boolean
        Public Property msg As String
        Public Property data As String

    End Class
```

And I am using the following code to deserialize

```
JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Client)(input)
```

The problem is that I can only use the public property, if I set the property to READONLY or PRIVATE SET, then the status/msg/data are not set.

I have been tried

```
        Private _status As Boolean
        Public Property status As Boolean
            Get
                Return _status
            End Get
            Private Set(value As Boolean)
                _status = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

AND

```
Public ReadOnly Property status As Boolean
```

Both will return nothing.

Would like to know if there is any way that I can make the property read-only? I am using public property right now, but I really don't want the value can be altered.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For PRIVATE SET, assuming you can modify the class, you can apply `<JsonProperty()>` to the property as shown in [JSON Serializer object with internal properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26873755/3744182).  If READONLY, you need to deserialize using a parameterized constructor as shown in [Avoiding default constructors and public property setters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35245256/3744182) (which also works for properties with a private setter).  Those answers are for c#, do they answer your question, or do you need a vb-specific answer?

Comment: You can also use `Public ReadOnly` fields (instead of properties) decorated with `<JsonProperty>`, without any *specialized* constructor.