# How to force c# NewtonSoft deserializer to use already created object for deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, reflection, json.net

While doing

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value, type);
```

A new object is created of given `type` for deserialization. What my requirement is I want to use already created object for deserialization

```
CustomObject obj = new CustomObject(); //passing constructor args
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value, obj);
```

But this overload is not available.

**So, is there any workaround so that I can use the already created object instead of creating new type through Deserializer.?**

**Why do I want to do so? (Detail)**

I am writing a generic mapper from JSON to c# classes. Structure of JSON looks like

```
  {
    "ActionType" : "LogEvent", //this is actually class name in a specific namespace
    "Settings"   : {
           "FailureRetries" : 4,
           "LogChannel"     : 1234 // log channel id, implementation detail
     }
  }
```

What I do in the configuration mapper is as follows

```
public void IAction GetActionFromConfig(){

    dynamic config = configManager.Load<dynamic>(); //loads JSON file.
    string className = config.ActionType; //from config we will get file name.
    Type type = Type.GetType(nameSpaceForConfig + "." + className);

    string  settingValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config.Settings);
    object actionObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(settingValue, type);

    return (IAction)actionObject; // return the IAction from config.
}
```

My problem is the `IAction` implementation classes might have some dependencies in the constructor (such as `ILogger`) and by default, deserialization won't initialize the constructor parameter. I know I can override the `JsonConverter` for the constructor initialization but as I am writing a generic mapper I can't give the specific arguments using custom `JsonConverter`.

What I am planning to do is first create a dictionary that will map `Type` (c# `Type` class) to a specific implementation for dependency resolution.

Second I will get the constructors of given action type (type given in config with `ActionType` parameter)

```
Type type = Type.GetType(nameSpaceForConfig + "." + className);
var ctors = typeof(type).GetConstructors();
var ctor = ctors[0];
List<Type> constructorArguments = new List<Type();
foreach (var param in ctor.GetParameters())
{
     constructorArguments.Add(param.ParameterType);
}
```

Then I will query the dictionary created in step 1. to get the arguments for the constructor.

Finally, I will use the `Activator.CreateInstance()` (passing the constructor dependencies got in previous step).

And then use this object for deserialization to initialize the public properties through the config file.

*So, this is why I require deserialization to happen on the `object` not on the `type`.*

**NOTE:** Pre-condition is each action should have one constructor with all the dependencies.

Aside: `configManager.Load<T>` implementation

```
public T Load<T>() where T : class, new() => Load(typeof(T)) as T;
public object Load(Type type)
{
  if (!File.Exists(_configurationFilePath))
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);

  var jsonFile = File.ReadAllText(_configurationFilePath);

  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonFile, type, JsonSerializerSettings);
}
```

Comment: Maybe an idea for use not the default constrcutor
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017716/json-net-how-to-deserialize-without-using-the-default-constructor

Comment: @Codeman01101001 I can't use specific types while calling the constructor as `JsonConvert` would do as I am in a generic context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` method to populate an existing object. See [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm).