# Serialize Record members with System.Text.Json

Tags: json, f#, json.net, system.text.json

I am using self-referencing members on my records like this:

```fs
type Payload =
    { Id: Guid }
    member x.DerivedProperty = $"Derived Property using id: {x.Id}"
```

`NewtonSoft.Json` would serialize this, but after migrating to `System.Text.Json` it is not longer included when serializing.

Is it possible to configure `System.Text.Json` to include self-referencing members?

Edit: This appears to be a side effect of `FSharp.System.Text.Json`: https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.SystemTextJson/issues/92

Looking for a workaround.  Note that if I do not serialize `Payload` with `FSharp.System.Text.Json` then it is serialized as expected.

Comment: What happens if you don't serialize that particular type `Payload` with `FSharp.System.Text.Json`?

Comment: Then it is serialized as expected :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out in your question, the failure to serialize record member properties is a known limitation of [`JsonFSharpConverter`](https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.SystemTextJson/blob/master/src/FSharp.SystemTextJson/All.fs) from  [`FSharp.SystemTextJson`](https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.SystemTextJson), see *[Serializing member properties on record types #92](https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.SystemTextJson/issues/92)*:

> The output does not contain the member properties. Remove the converter in the options and it does get printed out.

But what does `JsonFSharpConverter` actually do for record types?  As it turns out, this converter is a [factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#sample-factory-pattern-converter) which manufactures a [`JsonRecordConverter<'T>`](https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.SystemTextJson/blob/master/src/FSharp.SystemTextJson/Record.fs) for f# record types.  From inspection of its source, the main advantage `JsonRecordConverter<'T>` brings is that it always constructs a record using its [parameterized constructor](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-reflection-fsharpvalue.html#PreComputeRecordConstructor).  This is required for all records in .NET Core 3.1, and may still be required **for internal records** in .NET 5 and later.<sup>[1]</sup>  In addition it may also be required to properly serialize any field at all of an internal record -- I haven't tested this. <sup>[2]</sup>

Since it seems you do not need the converter applied for your `Payload` type, you can opt out of using `JsonFSharpConverter` by encapsulating it in some [decorator factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that whose `CanConvert(Type)` method returns false for types for which you want to use default serialization.

For instance, you could create a converter factory that opts out of `FSharp.System.Text.Json` when some custom attribute is applied:

```
type JsonConverterFactoryDecorator (innerConverter : JsonConverterFactory) =
    inherit JsonConverterFactory ()
    member private this.innerConverter = match innerConverter with | null -> nullArg "innerConverter" | _ -> innerConverter // Guard against null if called from c# serialization code
    override this.CanConvert(t) = innerConverter.CanConvert(t)
    override this.CreateConverter(typeToConvert, options) = innerConverter.CreateConverter(typeToConvert, options)

type OptOutJsonConverterFactoryDecorator<'T when 'T :> System.Attribute> (innerConverter : JsonConverterFactory) =
    inherit JsonConverterFactoryDecorator (innerConverter)
    override this.CanConvert(t) = base.CanConvert(t) && not (t.IsDefined(typeof<'T>, false))

type JsonFSharpConverterOptOutAttribute () =
    inherit System.Attribute()

type OptOutJsonFSharpConverter () = 
    inherit OptOutJsonConverterFactoryDecorator<JsonFSharpConverterOptOutAttribute>(JsonFSharpConverter())
```

Then decorate `Payload` as follows:

```
[<JsonFSharpConverterOptOut>]
type Payload =
    { Id: Guid }
    member x.DerivedProperty = "Derived Property using id: {x.Id}"
```

Or if you prefer to opt out of `FSharp.System.Text.Json` for all records, define `OptOutJsonFSharpConverter` as follows:

```
type OptOutJsonFSharpConverter () = 
    inherit JsonConverterFactoryDecorator(JsonFSharpConverter())
    override this.CanConvert(t) = base.CanConvert(t) && not (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsRecord(t, BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic))
```

(You may need to experiment to get the most appropriate serialization for your records, e.g. you may need to check [`t.IsPublic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.ispublic?view=net-6.0) to re-enable `JsonFSharpConverter` for internal records.)

Whichever version of `OptOutJsonFSharpConverter` you choose, initialize your options as follows:

```
let options = JsonSerializerOptions()
options.Converters.Add(OptOutJsonFSharpConverter ())
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> See *[F# internal visibility changes Record constructor behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54169707/3744182)* for details.

<sup>[2]</sup> See *[Fields and methods on internal types are impossible to make public #2820](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/2820)*