# Exception parsing json with System.Text.Json.Serialization

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

My sample code is very simple:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class C {
  public C(string PracticeName) { this.PracticeName = PracticeName; }
  public string PracticeName;
}

var x = new C("1");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x); // returns "{\"PracticeName\":\"1\"}"

var x1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C>(json); // correctly builds a C

var x2 = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.Parse<C>(json);
```

the last line raises:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Text.Json.dll
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am I doing wrong ?

(Note this is on latest .NET Core 3 preview 5 with latest System.Text.Json 4.6.0-preview6.19259.10)

Adding a parameterless constructor prevents the exception however I don't want/need a parameterless constructor and Json.Net parses fine without it.

Is there a way to make System.Text.Json parse using the given constructor like Json.Net does ?

Comment: Have you tried to add parameterless constructor?

Comment: ok, adding a parameterless constructor prevents the exception however I don't want/need a parameterless constructor and json.net parses fine without it

Comment: I think, in general, a parameter-less constructor has always been a prerequisite in serializable types. thinking of .NET scenarios that I am familiar with. XML Serialization, etc.

Comment: see in my sample - Json.NET has no problem without a parameterless constructor , also I can't find any docs that it is needed

Comment: @kofifus have you checked this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23017892/4648586) previously?

Comment: @BagusTesa, again as seen above, Json.Net has no problem with desalinizing my object, and since there is a single constructor there is no need for the [JsonConstructor] attribute

Comment: Json.net assumes a constructor parameter to be a property, if the name is equal (except common naming convention). That said, Json support in [.net core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33115) is still an open issue. Consider posting there.

Comment: As of **.NET 5** deserialization of types with parameterized constructors using `System.Text.Json` now works, see [Deserialize anonymous type with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59313256/3744182).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In it's current state, JSON Support in .NET Core 3.0 [is still not finished](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33115#), and it seems only a parameterless constructor is supported. It might be, that that feature will be added in future.

One <s>workaround</s> option  would be to make a parameterless constructor for your serialized model, when you want to use the new Json API from the .net framework. Probably we shouldn't use constructors for plain datatransfer objects at all, hence I see it as option, not as a workaround.

If you search for a way, on how to migrate from an older version to .net core 3.0, or use `Newtonsoft.Json` anyway, this is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio):

[MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support):

Install [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) package, and register it to your services:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

[SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#switch-to-newtonsoftjson):

Install [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson) package

```
//Client
new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl("/chatHub")
.AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(...)
.Build();

//Server
services.AddSignalR().AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(...);
```

That way you should* be able to use Json.NET Features in .Net Core 3.0

<sub><sub>*I don't have installed it, so I can not test it</sub></sub>

Comment: For me `AddNewtonsoftJson` method doesn't exit.

Comment: Did you installed above nuget package and imported the namespace [`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/1189a2c294df55d7a67f1bc6ea74d74858f467bd/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/DependencyInjection/NewtonsoftJsonMvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L19)? Also notice it is an method on `IMvcBuilder` and not `IServiceCollection`. You need to use it with `AddMvc` as shown above @SaeedNeamati

Answer (score 2):

PracticeName needs to be a property, not a field. Try that w/ the parameterless constructor.

I developed a quick console program class. The class `C1` is converted via the Newtonsoft.Json package. The class `C2` is parsed via the System.Text.Json package.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestJsonParse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c1 = new C1("1");
            var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c1); // returns "{\"PracticeName\":\"1\"}"
            var x1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C1>(json1); // correctly builds a C1

            var c2 = new C2();
            string json2 = "{\"PracticeName\":\"1\"}";
            var x2 = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.Parse<C2>(json2); // correctly builds a C2
        }

        class C1
        {
            public C1(string PracticeName) { this.PracticeName = PracticeName; }
            public string PracticeName;
        }

        class C2
        {
            public C2() { }
            public string PracticeName { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post a code sample illustrating your suggested solution?

Comment: Thanks,  are you saying I can't serialize fields ? also I don't want an empty ctor, my real case involves a whole lot of classes many of them without an empty ctor, and Json.NET has no problem with that.

Comment: @kofifus With System.Text.Json, that seems to be the case (at least as far as the Parse method is concerned).

Comment: Did you read my edit comment? Please do not write the word *edit*. It's just noise. We already see this in the edit history ;)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Sorry about that. Still learning the etiquette.

Comment: So you're saying that System.Text.Json requires a parameterless constructor  whereas Json.NET does not ? do you have a reference for that ? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Json Support with System.Text.Json.Serialization is quite unstable. It is better to use NewtonSoft.Json as it is more stable and almost everyone uses that. If running a console app then from the folder in your terminal do [image]

You are not required to specify the version though. If using visual studio then use Nuget package manager to install Newtonsoft.json.

To read json from a file for example *data.json*

```
{
  "Name":"Logan",
  "Age": 30
  "Books": ["Infinity War", "End Game"]
}
```

Specify your properties example

```
class Person
{
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public int Age{get; set;}
  public IList<string> Books{get; set;}
}
```

then from the class you wish to access the json data do the following

```
string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"./data.json");
Person person = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<Person>(fileContent);
```

test it

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hi {person.Name} you are {person.Age} today read {person.Books[0]}");
```

For more info go to https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm