# Error when trying to share DB Context through and migrate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am starting to lean asp.net core 3 and I have an issue at present. I am trying to share my db context like I used to through a .net core dll but I have an error.

I have the following declared in my class.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to e container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext_Model>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppliedContext")));
}
```

The db context which I have in my core dll project solution.

```
public class DbContext_Model: DbContext
{
    public DbContext_Model(DbContextOptions<DbContext_Model> options)
      : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Policys> Policys { get; set; }

}
```

I have declared my  connection string below with password masked

> "ConnectionStrings": {
>       "AppliedContext": "Server=DESKTOP\MSSQLSERVER2017;Database=Systems;User
>   Id=sa;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

But When I do Add-Migration InitalCreate I get this error.

> Unable to create an object of type 'DbContext_Model'. For the
>   different patterns supported at design time, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Is sharing of the context no longer allowed between .net core libarys and a web site ?

> Edit 2

Please see screen shot which shows I am selecting the correct project.
[image]

> Edit 3

That seemed to cause an another error the suggestion below. So I added the nugets in for the json tooling but still get this error.

[image]

> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate System.MissingMethodException:
>   Method not found: 'System.Text.Json.JsonDocument
>   System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.Text.Json.JsonReaderOptions)'.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[]
>   args)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) Method not found: 'System.Text.Json.JsonDocument
>   System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.Text.Json.JsonReaderOptions)'. PM> dotnet ef migrations add
>   InitialCreate

Comment: You’re probably trying to create the migrations with the wrong project. You will have to use the one that actually _configures_ the context. Otherwise, the migration tool won’t be able to construct it. At least if you want to configure it that way.

Comment: Hi Please see screen shot that i am selecting the shared libary

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppliedContext"),
    options => options.MigrationsAssembly(<DB_PROJECT>)
```

Then you should be able to run this from within the folder that has the `DbContext` project:

```
dotnet ef migrations add <NAME> --startup-project <STARTUP_PROJECT>
```

Comment: Oh ok - I didn't know you were using 3.0. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487123

Comment: Try running `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-*` to update your `dotnet ef` tools then.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot in your **Edit3**,  your need to update EF Core related package to version 3.0 . In **Manage NutGet Packages** , check **Include prerelease** next to the search box and update them to latest version like below :

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Note :When adding migration ,  set your web application as the Startup project and set the class library as the default project where you want Migration folder generates.

Reference :https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-ef-core-in-a-separate-class-library/

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot of your **Edit3** seems to indicate that your EF tool version is outdated. You can check by executing:

```
dotnet ef --version
```

on the command line. If it's not `preview8`, then install it:

```
dotnet tool update dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-preview8.19405.11
```

(optionally use the `--global` switch).

*Beware*: EF preview8 has an additional [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17145) when used with [`HasData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding). It should be fixed in preview9 (which at the time of this writing is not out yet).