# How can I deserialize some subtree only

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a JSON document like

```
{
   "outer":{
      "inner":{ ... }
   }
}
```

How can I deserialize the value of `"inner"` (the `{ ... }`) into some type `MyType` using `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: Json.Net sample from the documentation https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Comment: I'm not using Json.Net

Comment: What version are you using?  .NET 5 or .NET Core 3.x?

Comment: I'm using .NET 5 @dbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 5, you can deserialize the JSON to an anonymous type that wraps the required type:

```
var myType = JsonSerializerExtensions.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonString, 
                                                               new { outer = new { inner = default(MyType) } })
    ?.outer?.inner;
```

Using the extension methods from *[Deserialize anonymous type with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59313256/3744182)*:

```
public static partial class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static T DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(string json, T anonymousTypeObject, JsonSerializerOptions options = default)
        => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, options);

    public static ValueTask<TValue> DeserializeAnonymousTypeAsync<TValue>(Stream stream, TValue anonymousTypeObject, JsonSerializerOptions options = default, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TValue>(stream, options, cancellationToken); // Method to deserialize from a stream added for completeness
}
```

This should be more performant than deserializing to an intermediate `JsonDocument`.  But note this will not work in .NET Core 3.x as that version does not support deserializing to types with parameterized constructors.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ixK00V).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the JsonDocument class. A section in the link below explains how it works with sample code.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-5.0) like this:

```cs
public class MyType
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}


var json = @"{
""outer"" : {
""inner"" :  {""id"":1}
}}";
using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json))
{
    var prop = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("outer").GetProperty("inner");
    var myType = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType>(prop.GetRawText());
}
```

But not sure that performance-wise (I think you can improve the performance of this naive solution using some [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047063/2501279), but still) it would be better than creating corresponding structure.