# How to ignore/unwrap object name when deserializing from JSON?

Tags: c#, blazor, system.text.json

I am trying to deserialize JSON that i receive from a webservice. The JSON looks like that:

```
{ "data": 
   [  
      {"name": "john", "company": "microsoft"}, 
      {"name": "karl", "company":"google"}
   ]
}
```

My model which i want to deserialize into:

```
public class employee {
   public string name {get; set;}
   public string company {get; set;}

}
```

The problem is, that i cannot deserialize using System.Text.Json because of that object name "data". How can i make the deserializer to unwrap / ignore the data tag and just start from whatever is inside that tag?

Comment: You could deserialize to an anonymous type `new { data = default(List<employee>) }` then access the `data` property as shown in [How can I deserialize some subtree only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67319571/3744182).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a wrapper object and use it for deserialization:

```cs
public class Root {
   public List<employee> data {get; set;}
}

var employees = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonString).data;
```

In case there a lot of different types contains this pattern you can make `Root` [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics):

```cs
public class Root<T> {
   public List<T> data {get; set;}
}

var employees = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root<employee>>(jsonString).data;
```

Note that `data` contains a collection of employees not a single record.

Also note that you can use recommended [Pascal casing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) for property names, deserializer should be able to pick it up (of it it does not - you can help it by providing `JsonSerializerOptions` with correct `PropertyNamingPolicy` set).