# How to read JSON value for single value?

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer

I have an application that returns the below JSON format with only 1 value:

```
{"isActive":true}
```

I can read the value by putting it into a dictionary as per below:

```
var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, bool>>(rawValue, JsonSerializerSettings.Web)!.value;
```

But it does not seem to be a good way to use a dictionary to store a single key/value.

Is there a better way to get the value from the JSON?

Comment: You could deserialize to an anonymous type `new { isActive = default(bool) }`.  See: [Deserialize anonymous type with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59313256/3744182).  For Json.NET see [Deserialize an Anonymous Type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just parse your json

```
using System.Text.Json;

bool isActive= (bool) JsonNode.Parse(json)["isActive"];
```

or using Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json

bool isActive = (bool) JObject.Parse(json)["isActive"];
```

Answer (score -1):

*Assuming your json is returned as a string.*
You should then use **dynamic** in your case and it works very well. Below are two methods, you can get what you are looking for:

```
using Nancy.Json;

string jsonString = "{\"isActive\": true}";
var jsSeralizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonTable = jsSeralizer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine("JSS Is Active? {0}", jsonTable["isActive"]);
```

**OR**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string jsonString = "{\"isActive\": true}";
var dynamicTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine("JC Is Active? {0}", dynamicTable["isActive"]);
```

Comment: [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) is obsolete and was never ported to .NET Core.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is useful for you, You can use the HashSet Collections as an alternative to dictionaries for storing a single value.

```
HashSet<>
```