# How to pass an instance of CultureInfo from Angular to Web API?

Tags: c#, angular, serialization, swagger, cultureinfo

I have the following call, which works as supposed to.

```
[HttpGet("translation")]
public ActionResult Translations(string id)
{
  CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(id);
  return Translation
    .GetTranslationByCulture(culture);
}
```

I wanted to try passing a full cultural info object to avoid the conversion in the API, like this.

```
[HttpGet("translation2")]
public ActionResult Translations2(CultureInfo culture)
{
  return Translation
    .GetTranslationByCulture(culture);
}
```

It kind of works **but** I'm not sure what string passed from Angular (or in Swagger, for that matter), that would be a proper serialization of the `CultureInfo` instance. I tried backward enginering it by returning an instance from my API but got an error 500 due to exceeded limit of circular references in the returned object (as the JSON serialization supports depth of 32 at best).

What do I send in to the parsed as an instance of a culture?

Comment: Since `CultureInfo` has no parameterless constructor you need a custom serializer for that. And for that I don't know what you going to accomplish that. I would suggest sticking with the 1. solution. [custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017716/json-net-how-to-deserialize-without-using-the-default-constructor)

Comment: maybe just send parameters for `CultureInfo` and instantiate it with parameters?

Comment: @StepUp You mean the way I'm showing in my question?

Comment: @Eldar You're saying *KISS*, right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yeah, like you do. Maybe just send more parameters if you want.

Comment: @KonradViltersten KISS and bunch of other things. In general if you are doing something hard to implement  you need to be accomplishing something better. Either provide a better api for the rest of the team which is easy to read and implement or make it restrictive to stick with business rules or it should handle some security layer etc.. I mean it should worth for the pain.