# "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [." exception when deserializing into a List<string> field

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonconvert

I have an object:

```cs
class Node
{
  public Node(string text)
  {
    Text = new List<string> { text };
  }

  public List<string> Text { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to round-trip an instance of this object to JSON using Json.NET like so:

```
var root = new Node("");

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(json);
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'Text', line 2, position 11.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
```

For some reason it just can't handle that `List<string> Text` field and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I'm literally trying to deserialise the string it JUST serialised. I could try write a custom converter but it doesn't seem like it should be necessary here.

Is there perhaps an attribute I can use to help it along?

Edit:

Created a new (.NET Framework Console App) project with just one `Program.cs` file with the following code in it:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json; // Version: 12.0.3
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Node
  {
    public Node(string text)
    {
      Text = new List<string> { text };
    }

    public List<string> Text { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var root = new Node("");

      var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
      root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(json);
    }
  }
}
```

Am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your `Node` class does not have a parameterless constructor.  Instead, it has a single parameterized constructor.  In such a case Json.NET will invoke the parameterized constructor, matching constructor arguments to JSON properties by case-invariant name.  Unfortunately, the argument `text` for the constructor **does not match the type of the property `Text`**.  Specifically, the argument is a single `string` while the property is an array of strings:

```
class Node
{
    public Node(string text /* A single string named text */)
    {
        Text = new List<string> { text };
    }

    public List<string> Text { get; set; } // A collection of strings named Text
}
```

Since the array of strings in the JSON cannot be deserialized to the single string required to construct your class, you get the exception you are seeing.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YCbM1t).

To solve this, your options include:

1. Adding a parameterless constructor.  Json.NET will call it by default:

   ```
   class Node
   {
       public Node() => Text = new List<string>();

       public Node(string text /* A single string named text */)
       {
           Text = new List<string> { text };
       }

       public List<string> Text { get; set; } // A collection of strings named Text
   }
   ```

   It could be private or protected if you mark it with [`[JsonConstructor]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm).

   Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nPACeX).
2. Changing the constructor to accept a collection of strings.  `params string [] text` would seem to be easiest:

   ```
   class Node
   {
       public Node(params string [] text)
       {
           Text = text.ToList();
       }

       public List<string> Text { get; set; } // A collection of strings named Text
   }
   ```

   Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DJypam).
3. Renaming the `text` argument in the constructor to something different, say `singletext`, is less than ideal because Json.NET will pass `null` for the missing constructor value, which will get added initially to the `Text` collection and will remain there unless the collection is subsequently replaced during deserialization.

   Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xDk07K).

Related reading:

- [`JsonConstructorAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonConstructorAttribute).
- *[JSON.net: how to deserialize without using the default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23017716/3744182)*

Answer (score -1):

So I solved the problem by renaming the field from `Text` to `DialogueText`, renaming it to `Texts` also solves it.

Since I had already tried to set the name via JsonProperty with no luck, my current assumption is that perhaps `Text` is a reserved field name that is hard coded to expect a `string`.