# Why does the following JSON not deserialize properly?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have encountered a rather weird issue while trying to deserialize a simple json into an object of type `D3Point`, which is used from a NuGet package.

The json looks like this:

```
string cJson = face["Edges"][0]["Coords"][0].ToString();
```

```
"{\"X\": 1262.6051066219518, \"Y\": -25972.229375190014, \"Z\": -299.99999999999994}"
```

And the deserialization attempt:

```
D3Point coord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<D3Point>(cJson);
```

After the above, coord's values are: `{0;0;0}`.

Below is the `D3Point` class.

```
public readonly struct D3Point : IEquatable<D3Point>
{
  public static readonly D3Point Null = new D3Point(0, 0, 0);

  public double X { get; }
  public double Y { get; }
  public double Z { get; }

  public D3Point(double coordinateX, double coordinateY, double coordinateZ)
  {
      this.x = coordinateX; 
      this.y = coordinateY;
      this.z = coordinateZ;
  }
}
```

What could be the problem and how would I be able to fix it?

Comment: your class (which is a struct, not a class, btw), does not compile. your constructor needs a body.

Comment: It does, I just haven't included its body.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann that's an external type

Comment: Presumably json.net is having trouble matching the json key `X` to the constructor parameter `coordinateX`

Comment: The *ultimate* problem here is that the serializer can't write to those get-only properties, and hasn't figured out to use the constructor - quite likely because the parameter names don't match the property names in an obvious way; if it was me, I'd use an intermediate DTO type that I control - a class that has get-set properties, and map to the custom struct afterwards

Comment: (The ctor body that you've posted won't compile either -- please make sure you post your *actual* code)

Comment: Please comment out constructor and check

Comment: @MarcGravell is correct. And forcing it using an attribute is not possible with 3rd party code either. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017716/json-net-how-to-deserialize-without-using-the-default-constructor

Therefore I think this *might* be a duplicate after all

Comment: I have updated the original post with the actual class. Sorry for the inconvenience. @MarcGravell thank you very much for your comment, I will follow your advice and see if I can sort it out. I have changed the json's coordinates from, for ex. "X" to "coordinateX", following canton7's advice but it still does not work. I will, however, try it out with a DTO type now.

Comment: @VaibhavDeshmukh I do not have access in `D3Point` as I got it from a NuGet package

Comment: @Sascha not really a duplicate I suppose as, in my case, I can not add attributes to the members inside `D3Point`, and most solutions in that post are involving changes in those classes

Comment: @Radu while deserialize create a new class with X, Y,  Z properties and then assign it to D3Point

Comment: Your constructor has errors, btw. `this.x` etc do not exist

Comment: you can use `init;` property with C# 9.0.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just interim via a `Dictionary<string, double>`

```
//local or method
D3Point toD3Point(string json) { 
  var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, double>>(json); 
  return new D3Point(j["X"],j["Y"],j["Z"]);
}
        
D3Point coord = toD3Point(cJson);
```

If you really wanted to one-line it, using LINQ is a bit nasty, but..

```
new[]{ JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, double>>(cJson) }.Select(j => new D3Point(j["X"],j["Y"],j["Z"]).First();
```