# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throwing error after adding AddNewtonsoftJson()

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, blazor, deserialization

For using Patch in my Blazor application, we have used `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()`. But after adding it everything works fine if we dont return valdiationerror into response. When we return validation response, it throws an error as below,

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'validationResult.validationResults[0].memberNames', line 1, position 493.
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'validationResult.validationResults[0].memberNames', line 1, position 493.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
```

This is what I have done for grabbing response(please ignore the error at Mymodel, I changed it for screenshot only). It breaks at DeserializeObject only when res has validationresults.

```
response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync(Constants.uri, editModel);
var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var validationResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mymodel>(res);
```

And when I we will remove .AddNewtonsoftJson(), it returns proper validation message but Patch wont work!

Mymodel looks like this:

```
public class MymodelResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public int MymodelId { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public long? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string? Notes { get; set; }

    public MymodelResponse(List<ValidationResult> validationResults) : base(validationResults)
    {

    }
}
```

And `BaseResponse` has a property

```
public List<ValidationResult> ValidationResults  { get; set; }
```

Which is set in the constructor.

Comment: What does `Mymodel` look like?  Does it have a `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult` property?

Comment: @dbc I have updated my question with model. And yes it have System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult  property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as described in the error message: Json.NET is unable to choose a constructor for [`ValidationResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult.-ctor?view=net-7.0) because it has two public parameterized constructors and no default constructor, and Json.NET has no logic to prefer one parameterized constructor over another.

Since [`ValidationResult`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/ValidationResult.cs) is a simple type with two properties, you could create a [custom `JsonConverter<ValidationResult>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) for it:

```
public class ValidationResultConverter : JsonConverter<ValidationResult>
{
    record DTO(string ErrorMessage, IEnumerable<string> MemberNames);       
    public override ValidationResult ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ValidationResult existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Deserialize<DTO>(reader) is {} dto
            ? new ValidationResult(dto.ErrorMessage, dto.MemberNames)
            : null;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, ValidationResult value, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new DTO(value.ErrorMessage, value.MemberNames));
}
```

Then add the converter to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` and deserialize like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ValidationResultConverter() },
};
var validationResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mymodel>(res, settings);
```

And/or add it in `AddNewtonsoftJson()` as follows

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>
{
    opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ValidationResultConverter());
});
```

Notes:

- If you were able to modify `ValidationResult` you could mark the [`ValidationResult(string?, IEnumerable<string>? memberNames)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-componentmodel-dataannotations-validationresult-ctor(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))) constructor with [`[JsonConstructor]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) to inform Json.NET to use that constructor.
- For more complex types, you could consider creating a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that selects the appropriate constructor, such as the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865022/3744182) by [Zoltán Tamási](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1323504/zolt%c3%a1n-tam%c3%a1si) that selects the parameterized constructor with the longest argument list.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TaKdD6).