# JSON Deserialize System.Web.Mvc.SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I am having an issue deserializing my `SelectList` inside an object. My class is set up like so:

```
public class DropDownControl
{
    public string Type
    {
        get { return "ddl"; }
    }
    public SelectList Values { get; set; }
}
```

The object I have created is simply

```
var myControl = new DropDownControl()
{
    Values = new SelectList(
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "A"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "B"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "C"},
        }, "Value", "Text", "1"
    )
}
```

and I am getting the error

> Cannot create and populate list type System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.

When calling

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Control>>(myControl, _settings);
```

Certainly there has to be some way to serialize/deserialize a `SelectList`?

Comment: Where does JSON and serialization come into this question?

Comment: I seem to be getting this error when calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Control>>(json, _settings)`

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Because `SelectList` has no default (i.e. parameterless) constructor, you're going to need to write a custom converter in order for JSON.NET to know how to instantiate it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312048/120955) might help you learn how to do that.