# How to pass parameter to constructor deserializing json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have a small problem with passing some parent instance to a constructor when deserializing an object with `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Let's assume i have the following classes

```
public class A
{
    public string Str1 { get; set; }

    public IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public B(A a)
    {
        // a should not be null!
        Console.WriteLine(a.Str)
    }
}
```

And now i serailze and than deserialize the object `a` like this:

```
A a = new A()
a.Bs = new List<B>()
a.Bs.Add(new B(a));
a.Bs.Add(new B(a));
a.Bs.Add(new B(a));

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);

// Here i need to call the constructor of B when creating new instances
var newA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```

The problem is, that when deserializing the object, `null` will be passed to the constructor of `B`. Does any one has solved this issue/problem before?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you really need this, you may want to alter your design. If you can't serialize and then deserialize and object, you shouldn't use it in serialization.

Comment: I don't get any error message, the passed value is just `null`. Changing the architcture is not really possible, because this would cause a lot of refactoring work.

Comment: I mean if your class relies on an internal member, you cannot trivially deserialize it. Serialization by default works on public members only. You might want to make A public, or make it serializable in another way.

Comment: Currently i have no internal member. So what do you mean with making `A` public?

Comment: What do you do with `A a` in the ctor then? Again, if you need logic to run upon deserialization, the class is probably not viable for using in serialization. Anyway see [How to pass arguments to a non-default constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254503/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-non-default-constructor) if you really need it and don't want to redesign.

Comment: `A` will not only be used in the ctor. I just want to simplify the question. But `A` has some properites and methods, which needs to be accessed from `B`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your question and comments you've said that the class `B` does not have any public property for `A`.  So, when you serialize `B`, then no `A` will be written to the JSON, because Json.Net only serializes the public information by default.  Therefore, when deserializing, there will not be enough information to recreate `B`, because there is no `A` in the JSON.  So, step one is making `B`'s reference to `A` visible to Json.Net.  If you don't want to make it public, that is fine, but you will at least need to mark the member with a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to allow Json.Net to "see" it.

```
public class B
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private A a;

    public B(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;  // be sure to set the A member in your constructor
    }
}
```

Now if you do the above you will run into a second problem: your class structure has a reference loop (`A` has a list of `B`s which each refer back to `A`), and the serializer will throw an exception by default in this case.  The solution is to set the serializer's [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) setting to `Objects` (the default is `None`).  This will not only allow the serializer to handle the reference loops during serialization, but will also preserve the original references during deserialization, so that all the `B`s will refer to the same `A` instance.  (This is accomplished via special `$id` and `$ref` properties that are written into the JSON.)

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, settings);

var newA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json, settings);
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N0FUID

Comment: Works perfectly, just what i was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

What I like to do it I have to pass objects in a constructor is to create the object first using my default constructor and then  call populate object to set all properties that are not skipped as I decorated the properties with [JsonIgore]

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() 
{ 
  Error = HandleJsonDeserializationError,
  PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects 
}
var myObject = new ComplexObject(param1,param2);
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, myObject, settings);
```

You can continue populating objects and deal with any issues if you handle serialisation errors in the JsonSettings property. The signature is as follows:

```
static void HandleJsonDeserializationError(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs errorArgs)
{
   var currentError = errorArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
   errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
   //loging framework logs the error, set brake point etc when debug.
   Logger.Log(currentError, LogLevel.Exceptions);
}
```