# Parse String as UTC DateTimeOffset When No TZ Specified

Tags: c#, json.net, datetimeoffset

I am developing a simple web API client. On of my models has a `ExpiresOn` property that I have specified as a `DateTimeOffset`.

```
public class Model {
    public DateTimeOffset ExpiresOn { get; set; }
}
```

I deserialise the API reponse from a JSON string using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()`. I have noticed that since the JSON I retrieve doesn't specify any time zone information, JSON.Net will assume it's in local time and return me a `DateTimeOffset` adjusted to UTC, as per my settings. I have tried different combinations but I cannot seem to 'force' `JsonConvert` to read the string as if it were UTC.

Preferably, there would be an option to set that setting globally using `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` as I have similar parsing to be done in several locations.

Also, I am coding for ASP.Net Core 2.1, and my host's tz is set to CEST (+02:00). Setting a different time zone on the host is not an options.

Addendum:

An example of `string` to parse would be `"2018-07-09T11:22:33.45678"`. I've tried permutations of `DateParseHandling` and `DateTimeZoneHandling` but all return a date: `2018-07-09T11:22:33.45768+02:00`.

Obviously the deserialiser assumes that the string is in local time. Hence, is there a way to have it treat it as `AssumeUniversal` would in `DateTimeOffset.TryParse`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you tell JSON.Net to serialize DateTime as Utc even if unspecified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302902/can-you-tell-json-net-to-serialize-datetime-as-utc-even-if-unspecified). This of course only works if all your dates are in UTC.

Comment: Serialising isn't the issue. It's on deserialising.

Comment: Well, have you tried these settings on deserialising? They also apply to deserializing. Also, providing some strings of what dates you want to deserialize would also help.

Comment: I edited the quedition to reflect my issue.

Comment: Interesting, it does indeed do nothing for DateTimeOffset (see my answer). However you want to solve this, you probably won't come around using a `JsonConverter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `DateTimeZoneHandling` doesn't work for `DateTimeOffset`.

As a workaround you would have to define a `JsonConverter` that circumvents this problem:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null) return null;
        DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)reader.Value;
        return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeOffsetConverter))]
    public DateTimeOffset ExpiresOn { get; set; }
}
```

And then call  it like this:

```
var str = "{\"ExpiresOn\":\"2018-07-09T11:22:33.45678\"}";
Model test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(str, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime
});
Assert(test.ExpiresOn.Offset.Ticks == 0);
```

---

You can also define the `JsonSerializerSettings` in `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` instead of every conversion call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! #abolish-timezones :)

Comment: Also as an aside, would putting this JsonConverter in the Converts for the DefaultSettings callback work for all DateTimeOffset objects?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can pass `DateTimeZoneHandling` through `JsonSerializerSettings`

[Here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm) is the example for that though example here is for serializing but you can pass same settings for deserializing also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351273/how-to-pass-parameter-to-constructor-deserializing-json)

**Example:-**

```
string jsonWithUtcTimeZone = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flight, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
});
```

**Deserialization Example:**

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, settings);

var newA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json, settings);
```