# json deserialization GET, gets called before Set

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a few classes that map to below structure/hierarchy.

```
public class CustomModel
{
     public string Message { get; set; }

     public int Code { get; set; }

     public CustomData Info { get; set; } 
}

public class CustomData 
{

    public CustomData (CustomObject customData)
    {
        CustomObjectProp = customData.customMessage
    }
}

public class CustomObject 
{
    public string CustomObjectProp {get; set;}
}
```

When serializing CustomModel I get a Json string like below

```
{
  "Message ": "A message is set.",
  "Code": 825,
  "Info": "Some Info is set"
}
```

However when deserializing I get an `System.NullReferenceException` error as the constructor of `CustomData` gets called with customData being null.

How can I avoid the 'getter' to execute before the setter?

Comment: Are you using [Json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json) to deserialize the json?

Comment: @BrandonMinnick - yes, am using json.net

Comment: I would suggest adding a default constructor also and setting up some default data. Other than that you could look into writing a customer converter to handle the parameterized constructor : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254503/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-non-default-constructor/8312048#8312048

Comment: does that even compile? your type hierarchy doesn't conform to the specified json.

Comment: Hi Noah! Let me know if my answer, below, helped solve your problem! If it did, let's mark it as Answered to help future developers who may have the same question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the Null Reference Exception, perform a null check in the constructor.

```
public class CustomData 
{    
    public CustomData (CustomObject customData)
    {
        if(customData != null)
            CustomObjectProp = customData.customMessage
    }
}
```

If you are using C#6, you can take advantage of the [Null Conditioner Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) to perform the null check in-line.

```
public class CustomData 
{
    public CustomData (CustomObject customData)
    {
        CustomObjectProp = customData?.customMessage
    }
}
```